# How to modify column of one table to AUTO_INCREMENT which is foreign key for other table?

Tags: mysql, xampp

SQL query: copy

```
ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1833 - Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'posts_ibfk_1' of table 'techblog.posts'

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the foreign key.  In your case:

```
alter table posts drop constraint posts_ibfk_1;
```

Then you can change the column and add the foreign key back again:

```
ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;

alter table posts add constraint foreign key (id) references categories (id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbb5ef7693facf74300c65027503affb) is a db<>fiddle.